# Where is the admin path located in database?

Tags: magento2, database, url, magento-2.0, admin-panel

I want to find out where does Magento2 keeps it's admin path in the database?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think Magento 2 admin path is stored in the database.

You can find the randomly generated path in the `app/etc/env.php` file, e.g.:

```
'backend' => 
array (
  'frontName' => 'admin_1ai8c5',
)
```

Also an easy way to retrieve the admin path is by using the following Magento 2 CLI:

```
php bin/magento info:adminuri
```

Comment: Thanx for the info. I also had a doubt on it. Is there a way to change the admin url?

Comment: @Sukeshini yes you can follow the official documentation to do so: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-adminurl.html

Answer (score 2):

you can find base_url & many core cofig detail in **core_config_data** table (if you really want to the table).

& if you want to change admin URL always prefer CLI as below command:

`bin/magento setup:config:set --backend-frontname=admin`

Answer (score 1):

## In Case You Cannot Access The Admin

If like me you could not access the admin, you will need to add a `core_config_data` configuration with the path:

```
INSERT INTO `core_config_data`(`scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`)
VALUES(
    'default', # Or whatever your Scope is
    0,         # Or whatever your Scope ID is
    'admin/url/use_custom',
    1
);
INSERT INTO `core_config_data`(`scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`)
VALUES(
    'default', # Or whatever your Scope is
    0,         # Or whatever your Scope ID is
    'admin/url/custom',
    'https://my.url.com/newadminpath/'
);
```

Then run the CLI command:

```
php bin/magento setup:config:set --backend-frontname="newadminpath"
php bin/magento maintenance:enable 
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```